# How can I insert image to Google spreadsheets using Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets

Can I upload image to Google spreadsheets from my local computer directly using Python? Or I should upload image to Google Drive and then insert image to sheets by url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to upload the image to Drive or an external image hosting service and insert the image by URL. Sheets API doesn't have the functionality to upload image from a local machine.*

#### References:

- [Upload files | Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

Comment: @FernandoIrarrázavalG `Insert > Image > Google Drive`.